# for what values of $\ \overline z = z^n $

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose I have a matrix $\ D $ with the determinant $\ \det D = \overline z - z^n $ and I want to know when this expression is $$\ \overline z - z^n = 0 \\ \overline z = z^n \\ ?? = r^n(\cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta) $$

not sure how to procceed from here?

Comment: Write down $\bar z$ on the lhs.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean lhs?

Comment: Lhs is usually Left Hand Side, that is, what is at the left of the $=$

Comment: If $z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\cdot\sin(\theta))$, then $\bar{z}=r(\cos(\theta)-i\cdot\sin(\theta))$

Comment: Oh thanks!! So if $\ r^n = r $ then $\ r = 1 $ ? and if $\ i \sin \theta = - i \sin n \theta $ then does it mean $\ \theta = 0 $ ??

Answer (score 1):

Start by letting $z=a+bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Therefore, the given equation becomes,

$(a+bi)^n=a-bi$

Expanding the left hand side using binomial theorem.

Now, equate the real and imaginary parts across the two sides.

Solve the system of equations for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\bar z = z^n \implies z=0 \quad \lor  \quad z^{n+1}=|z|^2=1$$

Comment: if $\ z^{n+1} = |z|^2  = 1 $ then $\ r = 1 $ and then what?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
\overline{z}&=z^n
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Assuming $n\in\mathbb{N},\ n>0$
we have a solution $z=0$.

Another trivial case:

\begin{align} 
n&=1
,\\
\overline{z}&=z
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}
In this case any $z\in\mathbb{R}$ is a solution.

Let $z\ne0$, $n>1$. 
Then for $z=|z|\exp(\theta\cdot i)$
we have

\begin{align} 
\overline{|z|\exp(\theta\cdot i)}&=
(|z|\exp(\theta\cdot i))^n
,\\
|{z}|\exp(-\theta\cdot i)&=|z|^n\exp(n\theta\cdot i)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\exp(-\theta\cdot i)&=|z|^{n-1}\exp(n\theta\cdot i)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}.

hence

\begin{align} 
|z|&=1
,\\
n\theta &=-\theta +2\pi k
,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}
,\\
\theta &=\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}
.
\end{align}

Thus, for $n>1$ we have non-trivial solutions of the form

\begin{align} 
z&=
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)
+
i\cdot\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\right)
,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}
.
\end{align}